# What happens when Vce is more than the value in the datasheet?

Tags: bjt, gain

I read in a datasheet about DC current gain. In the picture they say that when I<sub>C</sub> = 150 mA and V<sub>CE</sub> = 10 V, h<sub>FE</sub> is between 100-300. I want to know what happens to h<sub>FE</sub> when V<sub>CE</sub> is more than 10 V or lower.

[image: picture]*

Comment: Usually the datasheet would have charts about typical behaviour. Does yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to know what happen to hfe when Vce is more than 10 V or lower*

The voltage of 10 volts is just a nice handy figure that guarantees the BJT is in its active (non-saturated) region: -

[image]

So, if you take the above characteristic (from [here](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Semiconductors/bjt_05.php)) and concentrate on the base current line of 2 mA, you can see that h<sub>FE</sub> remains fairly constant all the way up to 40 volts. OK, there will be a point when you reach the maximum V<sub>CE</sub> ratings and things go wrong but, generally, above 10 volts, h<sub>FE</sub> remains pretty constant.

There is also "Early effect" that modifies the current gain too: -

[image]

Image taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_effect).

Below about 5 volts V<sub>CE</sub> current gain drops towards a low value. Of course, for each BJT, the point when h<sub>FE</sub> starts to drop will vary.

Comment: Thank you Sir .Now I understand more. But I have a question you said that hFE fairly constant why is hFE value between 100-300 why not constant.

Comment: @Heroz one figure is the minimum for all transistors made and one figure is the maximum for all transistors made <-- manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: Sir. Does it mean that when I bought bjt transistors hFE will random between 100-300.

Comment: It could mean that or, they could be clumped closer to one end or the other or the middle. It's down to statistics.

Comment: So we need to use negative feedback to solve this problem right?

Comment: That's the usual way of confining the problem of variable gain.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I understand when Ic=150mA Vce 10V hFE is between 100-300. And when Ic=150mA Vce is 1 or more than 10 V, hFE will be between 100-300 right?

Comment: @Heroz there's probably better information in the data sheet in the form of graphs. Link me the data sheet for your specific transistor please.

Comment: https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/659179/ETC/Q2N2222/1

Comment: @Heroz figure 3 appears to tell you most things about how a typical device's hFE changes against collector current and temperature and it gives two graphs; one at a Vce of 1 volt and one at a Vce of 10 volts.

Comment: Thank you . But in figure 3 tell about value of Vce when lower than 10 V And What happen when   Vce is more than 10 V

Comment: When Vce is more than 10 look at the first graph in my answer; hFE should be fairly constant only to be modified by the BJT early effect. One thing you should never rely on is a stable or predictable hFE; you can rely on it being above a certain value when designing an amplifier (for instance) but you should never design a circuit that relies on a precise value of hFE @Heroz

Comment: Thank you for answer me , now I understand.

Comment: It means that when Ic=150 mA , Vce 1 V /Vce 10V or Vce more than 10 V  for example 15 V  HFE is fairly constant right ?

Comment: You can't rely on anything being fairly constant in a BJT; that's why we design circuits that don't rely on using the full range of hFE; we use negative feedback to keep things steadier.

Comment: Sorry to ask you many question. I have one doubt in datasheet for example Ic=10mA Vce =10V they give minimum hFE value so it can  large than this right ?(there is no limit)  but when Ic=150mA Vce=10V they give range of hFE 100-300 there is limit  it cannot more than maximum value right ?

Comment: Correct, there is an upper and lower limit.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the datasheets give curves which also give a good indication of the comparable scale of different effects, and one of the important ones is temperature.

The following is from OnSemi's [2n2222 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf), and you can see that, up to about 50 mA, h<sub>FE</sub> depends more on temperature than V<sub>CE</sub>.  At 150 mA they diverge.

[image]

Comment: Sir. But why in temperature is 25 C why hfe is between 100-300.

Comment: In graph when Vce =10 V Ic=150 mA
Why hfe approximate about 300.